# Is Apache Hadoop 2.7.1 is compatible with Apache Sqoop 1.4.6?

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, sqoop

I have installed apache hadoop 2.7.1 and integrate apache sqoop 1.4.6. When I am trying to import from MYSQL database to HIVE using sqoop commands :

```
sqoop import \
--connect "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/assignment5" \
--username root \
--password cg \
--table emp_detail \
--fields-terminated-by ',' \
--lines-terminated-by '\n' \
--hive-home /user/hive/warehouse/assignment5.db \
--hive-import  \
--hive-table emp_detail
```

And I am getting the issue as :

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected
            at org.apache.sqoop.config.ConfigurationHelper.getJobNumMaps(ConfigurationHelper.java:65)
            at com.cloudera.sqoop.config.ConfigurationHelper.getJobNumMaps(ConfigurationHelper.java:36)
            at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DataDrivenDBInputFormat.getSplits(DataDrivenDBInputFormat.java:125)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeNewSplits(JobSubmitter.java:301)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:318)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:196)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1290)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1287)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
            at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1287)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1308)
            at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.doSubmitJob(ImportJobBase.java:196)
            at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runJob(ImportJobBase.java:169)
            at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runImport(ImportJobBase.java:266)
            at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.importTable(SqlManager.java:673)
            at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:497)
            at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
            at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
            at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
            at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
            at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
            at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
```

Could anyone tell me what this issue means?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21873050/pig-found-interface-org-apache-hadoop-mapreduce-jobcontext-but-class-was-expe and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25594447/found-interface-org-apache-hadoop-mapreduce-jobcontext-but-class-expected-error and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22630323/hadoop-java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror-found-interface-org-apache-hadoo -- the version of Sqoop that you try to use appears to be compiled against **Hadoop 1**

Answer (score 1):

Indeed seems that you are suffering from version conflicts.

Answering your *first question* about the compatibility. Yes it does
I am currently running

Hadoop 2.7.1.2.4.0.0-169

Sqoop 1.4.6.2.4.0.0-169

And they do work together.

Trying to answer the *second question*.

I will check that you are actually running this two versions by

```
hadoop version
sqoop version
```

Apart from that the only thing you might add to your import sentence, (probably not related with your problem) is specify the connection driver. For mysql I would use

```
--driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

However, I am not sure that your issue is related with the Driver. There is more info about drivers at [sqoop page](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.0-incubating/SqoopUserGuide.html#id1763114)

But coming back to the initial question about compatibility. I am pretty sure that it is compatible.

I would rather check the actual versions that are running on your system and your calls.

For more info about the changes on Hadoop across versions you can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14211205/1651940).

Comment: thanks Pleonasmik, but I also used --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver this command but getting same issue. my hadoop version is 2.7.1 and sqoop version is 1.4.6. Is sqoop relelated to java version

Comment: @brijeshMISHRA java version can affect this but in that case you will get some `Unsupported major.minor version` exception